# How to split Monday, July 1, 2019 12:00:00:000 AM

Tags: r, date, time, strsplit

I have read, studied, and tested, but I'm just not getting it. Here is my data frame:

```
                               MyDate TEMP1 TEMP2
Monday, July 1, 2019 12:00:00:000 AM  90.0  1586

Monday, July 1, 2019 12:01:00:000 AM  88.6  1581

Monday, July 1, 2019 12:02:00:000 AM  89.4  1591

Monday, July 1, 2019 12:03:00:000 AM  90.5  1586
```

I need to compare it to a second data frame:

```
   Date     Time A.B.Flow A.B.Batch.Volume

7/1/2019 14:47:46      1.0              2.0

7/9/2019 14:47:48      3.0              5.0

7/11/2019 14:47:52      0.0              2.0

7/17/2019 14:48:52      3.8              4.0

7/24/2019 14:49:52      0.0              3.1
```

I just have to combine the two data frames when the minutes dates, hours, and minutes match. The seconds do not have to match.

So far I have gleaned that I need to convert the first Column `MyDate` into separate Dates and Times. I've been unable to come up with a strsplit command that actually does this.

This just gives each element in quotes:

```
Tried, newdate <- strsplit(testdate$MyDate, "\\s+ ")[[3]]
```

This is better but "2019"is gone:

```
Tried, newdate <- strsplit(testdate$MyDate, "2019")
```

It looks like this:

```
[1] "Monday, July 1, " "12:00:00:000 AM" 

[[2]]
[1] "Monday, July 1, " "12:01:00:000 AM" 

[[3]]
[1] "Monday, July 1, " "12:02:00:000 AM" 

[[4]]
[1] "Monday, July 1, " "12:03:00:000 AM"
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I would love some input as to whether I am barking up the wrong tree.

I've tried a few other things using anytime and lubridate, but I keep coming back to this combined date and time with the day written out as my nemesis.

Comment: Yes, you are barking up the wrong tree. Use `as.Date` and with the appropriate formats to create date objects that you can compare.

Comment: Hi Cory,

Thanks for the input. I'm not finding a way to get as.Date to deal with "Monday".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get rid of the day (Monday, ...) in your MyDate field by splitting on ',', removing the first element, then combining the rest and converting to POSIXCt.

Assuming your first dataframe is called df:

```
dt <- strsplit(df$MyDate, ',')
df$MyDate2 <- sapply(dt, function(x) trimws(paste0(x[-1], collapse = ',')))
df$MyDate2 <- as.POSIXct(df$MyDate2, format = '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

And since you are not interested in the seconds part of the timestamps, you can do:

```
df$MyDate2 <- format(df$MyDate2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

You should similarly convert the Date/Time fields of your second dataframe df2, creating a MyDate2 field there with the seconds part removed as above.

Now you can merge the two dataframes on the MyDate2 column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I still stuck on the first bit. When I use your first line of code I get:

 "Monday"                " July 1"               " 2019 12:03:00:000 AM"

I appreciate the suggestion to get rid of Monday. I can ditch it logically. But, the code is not doing that for me yet. The 2019 being stuck with the time is also a problem. 

I know I could do the split based on 2019, but then I have to modify the code each year. Plus it seems messy that way.

What I am missing is how one splits based on the first comma, the second coma, and then a space.

Comment: Yes, but the second line of the code removes the 'Monday' part, then combines the July 1, the 2019 and time parts together to create "July 1, 2019 12:00:00:000 AM". The third line then converts this into a POSIXct timestamp

Comment: No need to split the as.POSIXct function can parse the entire date string: `as.POSIXct("Monday, July 1, 2019 12:00:00:000 AM", "%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S:000 %p", tz="")`

Comment: Good one, thanks @Dave2e. I was unfamiliar with the format flags you mention. But I see no difference in the time object returned when I change the AM to PM - am I missing something?

Comment: user2474226, Thank you! That worked great. I was able to use your example to convert the other data frame as well. Then a simple paste got my dates and times in each data.frame to match exactly. Now on to the next part. Thanks again!

Comment: Correction from previous comment: `as.POSIXct("Monday, July 1, 2019 12:00:00:000 AM", "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S:000 %p", tz="")`

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a hint:

Since you have time, you shouldn't used as.Date but rather as.POSIXct, imho.

```
x=c("Monday, July 1, 2019 12:00:00:000 AM 90.0 1586")
Months=c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")


GetDate=function(x){
x=str_remove_all(x,",")#get rid of the
mo=which(Months==word(x,2))
day=word(x,3)
year=word(x,4)
time=word(x,5)
as.POSIXct(paste(paste(year,mo,day,sep="-"),time))
  }

GetDate(x)
```